# Mongo query for multiple date ranges

Tags: mongodb, date

My payments collection contains data returned from Stripe Charges. The "created" attribute is a timestamp (unix epoch in seconds). I have a query that finds successful charges for a given member id within a date range and sums the payment amounts:

```
// start of the day for Jan 1, 2017 (unix epoch) 
var jan1 = 1483250400

// end of the day for May 1, 2017 (unix epoch)
var may1 = 1502000000

var pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      // Member id
      _id: ObjectId("597ceea6122ccfda71d011be"),
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      payments: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$payments",
          as: "payment",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $gte: ["$$payment.created", jan1] },
              { $lte: ["$$payment.created", may1] },
              { $eq: ["$$payment.status", "succeeded"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      paid: {
        $sum: "$payments.amount"
      }
    }
  }
]
db.members.aggregate(pipeline).pretty()
```

It returns data in the following format:

```
{
  "paid" : 190000
}
```

**The problem is I have several other date ranges that I'd like to query:**

- Jan 1 - July 15
- Jan 1 - Sept 15
- Jan 1 - Dec 31

**I can always do each query individually, but I'd rather do all of them at once.** I've tried using `$bucket`, but that doesn't support using the same lower end threshold of Jan 1.

I would like to have the paid number associated with each date range. **Ideally, the output would look like this:**

```
{
  "May 1": 190000,
  "July 15": 240000,
  "Sept 15": 250000,
  "Dec 31": 255000
}
```

Comment: Your 1st of May 2017 timestamp should actually be 1493596800?!

Comment: Actually, I need the end of the day for May 1, but thanks for pointing this out anyway. I could always adjust the timestamps to be start of the day for the following day: May 2, July 16, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that would be like so:

```
var jan1 = 1483250400;
var may2 = 1493683200;
var jul16 = 1500163200;
var sep16 = 1505520000;
var jan1NextYear = 1514764800;

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // I omit your match stage here but you will need it, obviously
    $project: {
      payments: {
        $map: {
          input: "$payments",
          as: "payment",
          in: {
            janToMay: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gte: ["$$payment.created", jan1] },
                    { $lt: ["$$payment.created", may2] }
                  ]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            },
            janToJul: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gte: ["$$payment.created", jan1] },
                    { $lt: ["$$payment.created", jul16] }
                  ]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            },
            janToSep: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gte: ["$$payment.created", jan1] },
                    { $lt: ["$$payment.created", sep16] }
                  ]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            },
            janToDec: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gte: ["$$payment.created", jan1] },
                    { $lt: ["$$payment.created", jan1NextYear] }
                  ]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "May 1": {
        $sum: "$payments.janToMay"
      },
      "Jul 15": {
        $sum: "$payments.janToJul"
      },
      "Sep 15": {
        $sum: "$payments.janToSep"
      },
      "Dec 31": {
        $sum: "$payments.janToDec"
      },
    }
  }
])
```

This is a pretty generic solution. In your particular case, however, you might want to extract the common part of all your filters to a separate filter step like so:

```
var jan1 = 1483250400;
var may1 = 1493596800;
var jul16 = 1500163200;
var sep16 = 1505520000;
var jan1NextYear = 1514764800;

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // I omit your match stage here but you will need it, obviously
    $project: {
      payments: {
        $map: {
          input: {
              $filter: { // here we drop all the elements that all of the below filters would drop anyway
                  input: "$payments",
                  as: "payment",
                  cond: {
                    $gte: ["$$payment.created", jan1],
                  }
              }
          },
          as: "payment",
          in: {
            janToMay: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $lt: ["$$payment.created", may1]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            },
            janToJul: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $lt: ["$$payment.created", jul16]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            },
            janToSep: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $lt: ["$$payment.created", sep16]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            },
            janToDec: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $lt: ["$$payment.created", jan1NextYear]
                },
                then: "$$payment.amount",
                else: null
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // the final project stage stays identical to the one in the above example
])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.